# How to add armature controls?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

First of all, I am really new to Blender so the question might seem dumb but I couldn't find something in the internet.

I've just finished rigging a character with all the bones. My question is how you can add bone controllers (the yellow cube, all the circles and arrows) like in the picture below.

[image]

I only find tutorials explaining how to add bones or link them to the mesh.

I am really happy that there is such a great Blender community. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess these are custom bones: If you switch your armature to Pose mode, then select a bone, go in the Properties panel > Bone > Viewport Display > Custom Object, you can select a mesh that will replace the basic bone shape.

Comment: Those circles and arrows look like controls added with the Rigify add-on, which you will need to enable in the Add-ons tab of the preferences dialog.

Answer (score 3):

These bone controllers are in fact extra bones themselves.

In Blender, controls for a rig are usually implemented as bones in that rig with the [deform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/animation/armatures/bones/properties/deform.html) checkbox disabled (this checkbox tells the armature modifier to whether to consider a bone or not for calculating the mesh deformation). The rigger will then make use of various [constraints](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/animation/constraints/introduction.html) to define how they control the deforming bones in the rig.

Control bones often use [custom bone shapes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/animation/armatures/bones/properties/display.html#custom-shape) to give each controller easily recognisable and understandable shapes. These shapes are defined other meshes that have been hidden away somewhere in the scene (on a hidden layer prior to 2.8 or in a hidden collection (2.8+)). Unfortunately Blender does not come with an easy to use library of these, although the Rigify addon will generate quite a few if you use it to generate a rig.